# Javascript/HTML gray out radio list?

Tags: javascript, input, radio-button

Is there a way I can 'gray' out an html radio list input? I know I can actually change the color.. But I want to make it so the radio button list cannot be toggled either. I also want it to 'highlight' or be toggled to a specific radio list while in this state.

So for instance with this radio list:

```
 <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Water"> Water<br />
 <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Lemonade"> Lemonade<br />
 <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Juice"> Juice<br />
```

I want the user not to be able to click/change the radio list. And I want the radio button to be associated with the 'Juice' option.

This needs only to be compatible with Internet Explorer.

I cannot use JQuery! Please don't paste JQuery because it will not help me!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to do this dynamically (i.e. with JavaScript) or just statically in the markup?

Comment: I need to do this dynamically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just disable it with the "disabled" property.

Give it an "id" to fetch it more easily:

```
document.getElementById("radioButtonX").disabled = true;
```

(It doesn't matter how you get a reference to the DOM node of course.) You can re-enable the element by setting the property to `false`.  When you disable it, you'll also have to set the "checked" property (to `true`) of whichever other button you'd like to be selected.

If you want to do it with HTML, you can use the attribute:

```
<input type=radio name=whatever value=xyz disabled=disabled> <!-- or just "disabled" with no value -->
```

Comment: why not `getElementsByName()` so no need to add extra markup?

Comment: if they're in a group and you disable the group by using getElementsByName() they all become disabled

Comment: @ZoltanToth well that's possible of course but with radio buttons it's a little awkward since they share the name. I find it generally useful to give radio buttons an "id" value anyway so that they can be targeted by a companion `<label>` element, which is a really good idea for usability reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Simply apply the 'disabled' attribute to the elements that you want disabled and 'checked' to the default.

```
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Water" disabled> Water
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Water"> Lemonade
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Water" checked> Juice
```